# Definition congruence modulo a set-theory ideal

Tags: general-topology

Let $I$ be a ideal (in the sense of set theory.) In my topology textbook, I read that *$A$ is congruent to $B$ modulo $I$* if $(A\setminus B)\in I$ and $(B\setminus A)\in I$ or, equivalently, if $A=(B\setminus P)\cup Q$ where $P\in I$ and $Q\in I$. I undertsand the first part of the definition, which could be rephrased as the symmetric difference of $A$ and $B$ is in $I$. What I don't understand is the second part of the definition, i.e., that this is equivalent to saying that $A=(B\setminus P)\cup Q$. Could someone please explain that to me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**One direction:** If $A=(B\setminus P)\cup Q$ for $P,Q\in I$ then $A\setminus B\subseteq Q$ so $A\setminus B\in I.$

Also, if $x\in B\setminus A = B\setminus ((B\setminus P)\cup Q)$ then $x\in B$ and $x\notin B\setminus P,$ so $x\in P.$ So $B\setminus A\subseteq P.$

**The other direction:** (Left to you.) On the other hand, if $A\setminus B,B\setminus A\in I,$ show:

$$A=(B\setminus (B\setminus A))\cup (A\setminus B)$$ so $P=B\setminus A$ and $Q=A\setminus B.$

Comment: Great explanation. Thank you!